# Two values on one progress circle

Tags: html, angular, typescript, svg

I'm using svg to create a circle progress component.
How can I create something like that?
[image: example]
Both of them have the same max value but for example a different type which i want to visualise for the user

html:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="199.738" height="199.739" viewBox="0 0 199.738 199.739">
        <g id="Group_164607" data-name="Group 164607" transform="translate(19155.625 21525.715)">
            <path id="Path_3795" data-name="Path 3795" class="cls-1"
                  d="M63.619,0A63.619,63.619,0,1,1,0,63.619,63.619,63.619,0,0,1,63.619,0Z"
                  transform="translate(-19055.756 -21335.875) rotate(-135)"/>
            <path #progress id="Path_3796" data-name="Path 3796" class="cls-2"
                  d="M63.619,0A63.619,63.619,0,1,1,0,63.619,63.619,63.619,0,0,1,63.619,0Z"
                  transform="translate(-19055.756 -21335.875) rotate(-135)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('progress') progress: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 this.progress.nativeElement.style.strokeDasharray = `300 10000`;
        this.progress.nativeElement.style.strokeDasharray = `${(MyOneValue / 100) * 300} 10000`;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. You have 2 values (both in range 0 to 100) and wish to display both in a single progress widget?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i want

Comment: Do you know how to make something like that?

Comment: Here is an example: https://medium.com/@mrovinsky/pure-react-donut-chart-component-9272cb8e1cc1

Comment: Do you have something silimar in angular instead?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example for this issue:
https://www.tutsmake.com/angular-13-doughnut-chart-example-tutorial/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).